# How to take Python output from PHP var_dump

Tags: php, python, html

I have the following Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
myargs = sys.argv[1]

mylist = ["foo bar qux", "uix nan col"]
for chunk in mylist:
    mems = chunk.split()
    mems.append(myargs)
    print mems
```

When executed the following `python test.py param` giving this results:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'qux', 'param1']
['uix', 'nan', 'col', 'param1']
```

What I want to do is to use PHP to call the above python script and parse the output.
I have this in my php code (index.php):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>MYCODE</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<BR>


 <?php echo '<p>This is the output of my code:</p>'; ?>
<?php
 $vars = eval(`python /misc/path_to_mycode/test.py param1`);
 var_dump($vars)
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But it prints this instead over the web:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [exec()](http://php.net/function.exec) in php.Try like this

```
<?php echo '<p>This is the output of my code:</p>'; 
 exec('python /misc/path_to_mycode/test.py param1',$out);
 var_dump($out)
?>
```

The `exec` function just return the last line from the result of the command.